# Android ?attr/colorAccent using incorrect color on API 21

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two buttons in my layout like this:

[image]

The one on the left has `android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorAccent"` and correctly displays purple. The button on the right has `android:backgroundTint="@color/button_color"` where `@color/button_color` is defined in XML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/gray"/>
    <item android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
</selector>
```

On android versions >22, both buttons correctly display purple, however on API 21 and 22 only (I haven't tested below as my app only supports >=21), the button that uses `android:backgroundTint="@color/button_color"` shows a (seemingly random) red color.

How can i make `?attr/colorAccent` display the correct color when used in `button_color.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure what causes this issue but i have worked around it by applying the `ColorStateList` in code like this:

```
button.setBackgroundTintList(
    new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, //Disabled
                    new int[]{} //Default
            },
            new int[]{
                    disabledColor,
                    defaultColor
            }
    )
);
```

To set `defaultColor` equal to the accent color attribute, i use the following method:

```
public static int getAccentColor(final Context context) {
    final TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, new int[]{android.R.attr.colorAccent});
    final int color = a.getColor(0, 0);
    a.recycle();
    return color;
}
```